# Showing text representation of Unicode symbol in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, emoji, python-unicode

I can do this in my ipython notebook:

```
print(u"\u2605")
```

> ★

But how do I go backwards? That is, going from the symbol to the unicode string. Encoding it in UTF-8 or UTF-16 is giving binary representations. For example:

```
print('★'.encode('utf-16'))
```

> b'\xff\xfe\x05&'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`unicode-escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings):

```
>>> '★'.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u2605'
>>> print('★'.encode('unicode-escape').decode())
\u2605
```

or [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) if you just want to know the codepoint:

```
>>> ord('★')
9733
>>> hex(ord('★'))  # as hexa decimal
'0x2605'
>>> print(r'\u%x' % ord('★'))
\u2605
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use [`ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii):

```
>>> print(ascii('★'))  # NOTE: surrounding quote
'\u2605'
>>> print(ascii('★').strip("'"))
\u2605
```

Comment: Or `ascii('★')`

Comment: @Robᵩ, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer to include that.